# Balancing the parentheses

Tags: c++, data-structures

I wanted to balance out the parentheses but i don't quite get it. I also got some errors when inputting parentheses and sometimes it accepts the input.
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string x;
    stack < char, vector<char> > iStack;
    
    cout << "Enter series of parentheses: ";
    getline(cin, x);
    
    for (int i=0; i<x.length(); i++)
      if (x[i] == '(' || x[i] == '{' || x[i] == '[')
          iStack.push(x[i]);
      else
      {  
        cout << iStack.top() << endl;
        iStack.pop();
      }  
    
    if (iStack.empty())
        cout << "Balance!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Not Balance!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: You only check for opening parentheses so how should the check whether they are balanced or not work?

Comment: This code would say that `{{{]]]` matched. When you encounter a closing symbol you need to make sure the top symbol on the stack is the matching opening symbol. You also need to check if the stack is not empty before you pop from it. Imagine input of just `}`. You mention errors but not what the errors are. You should explain them in detail.

Comment: In addition to not checking, if a non-opening bracket is actually correctly closing the previously encountered opening bracket, you've got another source of unwanted behavior: At any point in the string the number of non-opening brackets in the string up to that point exceeds the number of opening bracket, you'll try to read/pop the top element from an empty stack.

Comment: Also, the input `}{` will cause undefined behaviour, since it pops an element of an empty stack on the first iteration of the loop.    Don't make the mistake of assuming that input will always have an open bracket before its corresponding close bracket.   After all, checking for balanced parentheses must be able to detect all cases when the parentheses are NOT balanced.